# Can not separate input function in class with function with arguments

Tags: c++, constructor

Can not separate input function in this problem

In this code, i can not separate an input function. However, when i put the input in int main(), it show right solution. What is wrong with my code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test
{
    int a,b;
    public:
    void input();
    void swapValue(int value1, int value2);
};
void test::input()
{
    cin>>a>>b;
}
void test::swapValue(int value1, int value2)
{
    cout << "Swap value in function" << endl;

    int temp = value1;
    value1   = value2;
    value2   = temp;
    cout << "value 1: " << value1 << endl;
    cout << "value 2: " << value2 << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    test s1;
    s1.input();
    cout << "===============================" << endl;
    cout << "After the function call" << endl;
    s1.swapValue(a, b);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void swapValue(int value1, int value2);` same problem now: `value1` and `value2` are also _local_ variables, modifying them won't modify anything else. Please tell us what _exactly_ `swapValue` is supposed to do? Show us an example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
void test::input()
{
    int a,b;   // these are local variables
    cin>>a>>b;
}
```

The local variables `a` and `b` in `input` are, well, local to the `input` function, they cease to exist once the program has returned from the function, despite the fact that they have the same name as the variables `a`and `b` in `main`.

This is most basic knowledge that is explained in the first chapters of your programming text book.

You simply need to delete this line in `input`:

```
void test::input()
{
    // delete this line:   int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
}
```

BTW: the purpose of `swapValue` is not quite clear to me, but basically you seem to mix up class members and local variables.

Comment: oh i forgot to put that one in input function but it seems like the program still shows the wrong answer, can you try to run to see it?

Comment: @PeterNguyen you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55808358/edit) your question and show us an example of input and exepected output.

Answer (score 1):

In this function:

```
void test::input()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
}
```

You're not changing the `a` and `b` member fields of `test`. You're making new `a` and `b` variables that get discarded at the end of the function, leaving the member fields unchanged. Remove the `int a, b;` line to fix that.

Another issue is that you can't read `a` and `b`. `swapValue` doesn't do anything with them, so why is it even a member function? You have to pass references to `a` and `b` to `swapValue`, but they're private and there's no getter, so that doesn't work. I would recommend something like this instead:

```
void test::swapValue()
{
    cout << "Swap value in function" << endl;
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    cout << "value 1: " << a << endl;
    cout << "value 2: " << b << endl;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
s1.swapValue();
```

Now it is a member function that swaps the `a` and `b` fields, and as such, it doesn't need any parameters.